# "Ends with" logic referencing a list

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to categorize query phrases that have state modifiers at the end of the text string.

Example:

```
apple Cupertino, ca
beach
orange
orange, ca
```

Referencing a list of state abbreviations so the first and last cell would return TRUE.

Tried using this formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(A2,LEFT(A2,2)="*"&Sheet3!$A$1:$A$72&"*"))>0
```

But it is not working. Any idea how I could do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said that the state abbreviations should come *"at the end of the text string"*, and as I see in your example, it is always preceded by a blank (you dont want to match `abcdca` but `abcd ca` or `abcd, ca`).

This formula does that:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(A2,"* "&Sheet3!$A$1:$A$72))>0
```

---

The  *wildcard criteria* `"* "& "ca"` means "match something that ends with  space followed by ca".

Comment: Oh interesting thank you! Would you be able to explain to me what the asterisks in quotes tells the formula to do? Just so I can know how to modify it if I needed to adjust the formula for something else.